# flatpak run aplication error

Tags: command-line, gpu, flatpak

i tried to run flatpak apps after install it on terminal but it shown this :

MESA: warning: Kernel 4.1 required to properly query GPU properties.

after I run the run apps code it shown like above.

can you give me some solutions?

Comment: version/distro of Ubuntu? Read [ask] then [edit] accordingly

Comment: The oldest *supported* release for this site uses Linux 5.4, what are you using?